# How to send data in another page with a foreach loop and specific ID?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, fpdf

i have the follow code in PHP and HTML:

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['service1'])){
                        $sql = "SELECT u.id u.name, u.password FROM users u";
                        $result = conection($sql);
                        $data["tittle"] = "result";
                        $data["result"] = $result;
                        foreach($data["result"]as $smth){
                        $id = $smth["id"];
                        $name = $smth["name"];
                        $password = $smth["password"];
                    ?>
                        <table style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Password</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $password;?></td>
                                <td><a role="button" href='anotherpage.php' onclick="documents('<?= $id?>')" class='btn btn-primary' target="_blank"></td></tr>
                                </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                    }?>
```

And the JavaScript used in the button:

```
<script>
      function documents($id)
  {
       document.getElementById($id);
  }
   </script>
```

In the beginning I am receiving the option of "Service 1" through a checkbox to proceed with the script I showed above, the problem arises when I want to select an ID from the 3 that are shown to generate a report in FPDF, the script in FPDF is as follows:

```
<?php
        ob_start();
        require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Libraries/fpdf.php");
        class PDF extends FPDF
        {
            function Header()
            {
                
                $this->SetFillColor(0,90,151);
                $this->SetTextColor(0);
                $this->SetDrawColor(0,90,151);
                $this->SetLineWidth(.50);
                $this->SetFont('','B');
                $this->Ln(50);
                $this->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
                $this->Cell(3);
                $this->Rect(10,55,260,25);
                $this->Ln(10);
                $this->Cell(3);
                $this->Cell('0','0',$id." ".$name. " ".$password,0,0,'L');
                $this->Ln(20);
                
            }
        }

        $pdf=new PDF('L','mm','A4');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->Output();
        ?>
```

When I press the button it does not bring me the data depending on the ID that is selected at the same time as the option, does anyone know why this happens? or if I'm failing at something

Comment: Your JS doesn't do anything more than selecting the HTML element that has the same id as `$smth["id"]`. What was the expected result?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Hello bro, im new in this projects and i want to learn about this, I assumed that the data that was in the javascript was going to be sent later in the call of the reference that is seen in the button: "anotherpage.php"

Comment: Ah I see. So it's more like creating links with the appropriate data from the loop?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, The problem is to identify and select the ID that is being selected to generate that report in another link

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the core problem really related to HTML, SQL, or FPDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values to a link in the form of search parameters.
These parameters all have a **key** and a **value**.

The start of the search parameters is marked by a `?`.
Then specify the **key** and the **value** combined with an equals symbol `key=value`.
Key-value pairs are separated by an `&` symbol.

```
<a role="button" href="anotherpage.php?id=<?= $id ?>&name=<?= $name ?>" class='btn btn-primary' target="_blank">
```

You'll notice that when clicking the link the values are passed along to the URL. The server is able to read these values.

In `anotherpage.php` use the *superglobal* [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to access the values that are in the URL. `$_GET` presents the data as an *associative array*. This means that you can get a value by accessing the **key** in the array, like the example below.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

This method can expose sensitive data. So be sure to not print any data like passwords to the frontend for people to see. Keep that data on the backend.

Comment: this is actually a very bad idea, to send passwords as get about the web, without hashing them first.

Comment: Agreed, I've omitted the password output.

Comment: You're the best man, thanks for that detailed explain, people like you are blessed to share this knowledge